# What is the correct way to write the model equation for a linear probability model?

Tags: least-squares, linear-model

I'm trying to write down the equation describing a [linear probability model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_probability_model).

If I was writing out the equation for an OLS model with continuous y with observation unit *i* , I would write:

$$y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{i1} + \beta_2 x_{i2} + \epsilon_i  $$

If I were specifying the model for a probit model, I would write:
$$ Pr(y_i =1) = \Phi(\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{i1} + \beta_2 x_{i2}) $$
or something thereabouts.

To be clear, a linear probability model is just an OLS model in which Y is a 0/1 indicator variable for some particular outcome. I know this is kind of a pedantic question, but how do you formally indicate in the first equation that $y_i$ is an indicator variable for an outcome just so that it's clear from the equation what you are doing?

Alternatively, is this a silly question and you just write the first equation and clarify the meaning of $y_i$ in the text?

**edit:** Maybe I'm encouraging too much analysis here. Simply put, what would be the reasonable equation to write down in a basic empirical driven paper to say "this is the form of the model and the relevant data items" where you were running a linear probability model?

Comment: [*Estimating equation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimating_equations) is a term with a technical meaning. What you have here seem to be (partially specified) models.

Comment: Sorry, that's right. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Somehow your Wikipedia reference successfully manages to write down this model: what aspect of that reference, then, requires clarification?

Comment: @whuber I'm not sure that it does though. It writes $E[Y|X]$, which doesn't make it clear that Y is an indicator variable and then it writes $Pr(Y=1|X)$ which is a statement of probability rather than a factual statement of Y as an indicator variable. It strikes me that the correct thing to do is to explicitly declare Y as an indicator variable. Tell me why I'm wrong about this interpretation?

Comment: And indeed, Wikipedia explicitly declares $Y$ is an indicator.  What more is there to add?

Comment: @wildgunman The expectation of a 0/1 variable is the same as the probability its 1

Answer (score 1):

You could write both regression models (and all others) the exact same way:  $Y | X= x \sim p(y|x)$, for some conditional distributions $p(y|x)$.  The case of binary $Y$ implies that these distributions are Bernoulli.

OLS is an estimation procedure, not a model. The distributions $p(y|x)$ are not specified by stating "OLS."

On the other hand, OLS is a good estimation procedure to use when the $p(y|x)$ are normal, homoscedastic, and have a conditional mean function that is a straight line.